# Load transparent png into gd php but don't make it's background transparent

Tags: php, image, png, transparency, gd

I'm trying to create images from dynamic text data in GD and put a logo in the top corner. The background color of the image will change based on the data passed in so I can't just save the logo as an image with no alpha channel.

I create the image, fill it with the dynamic background color using imagefill(), then add the text using imagettftext() and then load my logo in. I'm having a problem getting the logo into the image without it keeping its background color of 'transparent'. So I would like it to have the dynamic background color behind it that is set with imagefill(). However, it keeps the transparency background it was loaded in with and so writes this part of the png as transparent. I tried calling imagefill() on the logo after it had been loaded in (using the same rgb that sets the background of the destination image) but this didn't do anything.

Below is my code:

```
$background = $_GET['background'];
$data1 = $_GET['data1'];
$data2 = $_GET['data2'];
$r = $_GET['r'];
$g = $_GET['g'];
$b = $_GET['b'];

$png_image = imagecreate(400, 200);
$gd_text_color = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 255, 255, 255);
$gd_background_color = imagecolorallocate($png_image, $r, $g, $b);
imagefill($png_image, 0, 0, $gd_background);

$text1 = "test test $data1";
$text2 = "test test again $data2";
$font = 'Lato-regular.ttf';
imagettftext($png_image, 18, 0, 20, 20, $gd_text_color, $font, $text1);
imagettftext($png_image, 18, 0, 20, 50, $gd_text_color, $font, $text2);

//trying to get this logo and place it in the corner.
$logo = imagecreatefrompng("images/logo.png");
imagecopy($png_image, $logo, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 30);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($png_image, $filename);
imagedestroy($png_image);
```

Here's the output of that code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvDZF.png
And here's what the image looks like when loaded into a program that accepts an alpha channel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SbLP.png

Does anyone know how I'd achieve what I'm attempting?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

To try and explain what I want here's another image. The top image is what I currently get, and the bottom image is what I want. I'm simply trying to load in a transparent PNG that can sit ontop of different colored backgrounds. However I either get it like how it is shown here (transparent background) or as a black background (because I guess the alpha channel isn't being looked at?). Hope this helps. Image: [image: Error on top, mocked up version of how I want it below.]

**Edit 2**

As per the comment below, I changed it from imagecreate() to imagecreatetruecolor() and now it works fine! I would love an explanation why this solved it if anyone has the time but for now, thank you all who commented or even spent your time looking at this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really trying to do - whether you want the final image to have any transparency or not. However, your `imagecreate()` may be causing you problems as it creates a palletised image - maybe you need `imagecreatetruecolour()`.

Comment: imagecreatetruecolor (not the British version!)

Comment: I'm trying to create an image that has no transparency, correct. I guess my explanation was confusing so I'll have another go: the background color of the final image will depend on the input data and so I can't just create a "logo" image with the same background color of the final image. So I'm loading it in as a PNG with transparency. I'm hoping to 'place' it in the top left so it sits ontop of the dynamic background color, however GD is making that part of the image transparent, which I don't want. I've included a screenshot in the main post showing what I currently have and what I want.

Comment: Oh wow! Ignore my last comment and my edit! imagecreatetruecolor() solved it. I was banging my head against a wall for about 3 hours total messing around with the alpha channels and the functions like imagealphablending()...Thanks for the help @MarkSetchell and @Ben-Shoval! I still don't understand why, but that works now! If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `imagecreate()` may be causing you problems as it creates a palettised image which doesn't have the flexibility or breadth of expression of a true-colour image.

I suggest you replace it with `imagecreatetruecolor()`.